# Extract frames from a video file as rgb array

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg

Is there a way that I can extract frame by frame from a video file. I need raw rgb data in my memory so i can calculate positions of objects. I tried doing that using ffmpeg in linux but i had a lot of problems, for example when I use function `av_register_all()` I get full screen of errors. [The tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html) describes pretty much what I need, but it's out of date and I cant compile it with new version of ffmpeg. Can someone help me with some advice on how to update/edit this code or different method of compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [mencoder](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mplayer#Mencoder) to extract images in jpg from a video and after turn into rgb.

```
mplayer input.avi -vo jpeg:outdir=dirname:quality=80
```

With ffmpeg, here you are a great [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626095415/http://linuxers.org/tutorial/how-extract-images-video-using-ffmpeg)